# setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content­-Type" Not Working

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

Simple as it is:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkURLString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:10];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content­-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]];
```

If I log the value for the header `@"Content­-Type"` I got nil. And that what I got at the backend. Every other value is set and even tried other header fields, works fine!. I tried setting the body before the header and still got nil.

Comment: I can't see why that shouldn't actually set the Content-Type header. Are you sure the request object isn't being released or anything like that?

Comment: It's not released and other parameters are working fine.

Comment: The easiest way to find a solution would probably be to put up a POC project on Github so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Seriously, @ValerioSantinelli? A POC on Github for setting the content type of URL request :) ?

Comment: :) to be honest I can't really find agood reason why that code shouldn't work just as is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to copy and paste your code and I obtained `(null)` as well.

By printing the list of all `HTTPHeaderFields` (`[request allHTTPHeaderFields]`) I got:

```
Content-Type: {
    "Content\U00ad-Type" = "application/json";
}
```

As you see, there is a strange Unicode character: `\U00ad`.
This is the reason why when you try to get the value associated with `Content-Type`, it finds `null`.

So I tried to reolace the string `@"Content-Type"` in your code, and the result was:

```
Content-Type: {
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
}
```

And indeed now, logging:

```
NSLog(@"Content-Type: %@", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]);
```

I obtained:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: First thanks for editing the post and making the code indented. Second, smart thinking for fixing the bug. I was copying the Content-Type header field from a PDF file. Didn't notice and it's paste in wrong encoding.

Comment: Avoid 'copy'->'paste' when you can :)